# SSL Configuration error on Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I have two different applications running on two different ports. The `default_server` application running on port 80 successfully redirects all `HTTP` requests to `HTTPS` but the second application running on port `18010` gives error while configured with Letsencrypt SSL.

Here is the Server Block file -

```
upstream cms-backend {
            server 127.0.0.1:8010 fail_timeout=0;
    }

server {
  listen 18010;
  server_name "";
  return 301 https://$server_name:18010$request_uri;
}

server {
  # CMS configuration file for nginx, templated by ansible

  # Proxy to a remote maintanence page

  # error pages
  error_page 504 /server/server-error.html;
  error_page 502 /server/server-error.html;
  error_page 500 /server/server-error.html;

  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;

  include snippets/ssl-cabacademie.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;


  # Prevent invalid display courseware in IE 10+ with high privacy settings
  add_header P3P 'CP="Open edX does not have a P3P policy."';

  # Nginx does not support nested condition or or conditions so
  # there is an unfortunate mix of conditonals here.

  server_name "";

  access_log /edx/var/log/nginx/access.log p_combined;
  error_log /edx/var/log/nginx/error.log error;

  # CS184 requires uploads of up to 4MB for submitting screenshots. 
  # CMS requires larger value for course assest, values provided 
  # via hiera.
  client_max_body_size 100M;

  rewrite ^(.*)/favicon.ico$ /static/images/favicon.ico last;


  # Blackholes an archive of python library files that instructors
  # may provide for sandboxed python problem types, the internal
  # directive will result in nginx emitting an nginx 404. Users
  # will not be redirected to the application 404 page.
  location ~* python_lib.zip {
    internal;
  }

# Common settings used across nginx configurations

# Disables server version feedback on pages and in headers
server_tokens off;

  location @proxy_to_cms_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

    # newrelic-specific header records the time when nginx handles a request.
    proxy_set_header X-Queue-Start "t=${msec}";

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://cms-backend;
  }

  location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_cms_app;
  }

  # No basic auth security on the github_service_hook url, so that github can use it for cms
  location /github_service_hook {
    try_files $uri @proxy_to_cms_app;
  }

  # No basic auth security on the heartbeat url, so that ELB can use it
  location /heartbeat {
    try_files $uri @proxy_to_cms_app;
  }

      # static pages for server status
  location ~ ^/server/(?P<file>.*) {
      root /edx/var/nginx/server-static;
      try_files /$file =404;
  }

  location ~ ^/static/(?P<file>.*) {
    root /edx/var/edxapp;
    try_files /staticfiles/$file /course_static/$file =404;

    # return a 403 for static files that shouldn't be
    # in the staticfiles directory
    location ~ ^/static/(?:.*)(?:\.xml|\.json|README.TXT) {
        return 403;
    }

    # http://www.red-team-design.com/firefox-doesnt-allow-cross-domain-fonts-by-default
    location ~ "/static/(?P<collected>.*\.[0-9a-f]{12}\.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$)" {
        expires max;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        try_files /staticfiles/$collected /course_static/$collected =404;
    }

    # Set django-pipelined files to maximum cache time
    location ~ "/static/(?P<collected>.*\.[0-9a-f]{12}\..*)" {
        expires max;
        # Without this try_files, files that have been run through
        # django-pipeline return 404s
        try_files /staticfiles/$collected /course_static/$collected =404;
    }

    # Set django-pipelined files for studio to maximum cache time
    location ~ "/static/(?P<collected>[0-9a-f]{7}/.*)" {
        expires max;

        # Without this try_files, files that have been run through
        # django-pipeline return 404s
        try_files /staticfiles/$collected /course_static/$collected =404;
    }

    # Expire other static files immediately (there should be very few / none of these)
    expires epoch;
  }


}
```

Whenever accessed the browser give this error -

Comment: You have two server blocks listening on port 18010 with the same server name. You also use `$server_name` which will expand to an empty string. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for guidance.

Comment: @RichardSmith No, I don't have two server blocks listening to port 18010. There is just one. The application structure is like this - 
Application 1 - port 80, server_name mydomain.com
Application 2 - port 18010, Now here the mydomain.com is same but i want this to listen to 18010
this is the problem

Comment: In your question I can distinctly see two `server` blocks each with a `listen 18010;` statement and a `server_name "";` statement.

Comment: @RichardSmith That was a typo. I corrected it and it is still not working.

Comment: Ok :-) The other problem is `return 301 https://$server_name:18010$request_uri;` which would attempt to redirect to itself, except that the scheme is wrong and `$server_name` is an empty string anyway.